# MVC - Create object and related objects in one go

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I want to create a parent object with child/related objects in the same view.
An example would be: create one Father (with some name) along with all his sons (with their names). I have created a view model:

```
public class FatherViewModel {
  public Father father {get; set;} // has 1 property Name
  public List<Son> {get; set;} // has 1 property Name
}
```

My question is, how do I get the list of Sons back from the view when the post is performed?
I have tried using HiddenFor for each Son id, but no matter what, the list is empty when returned to the controller.

**UPDATE:**

I tried the Editor Template example by Shyju described below, but my editor is never called.
I have 1 object:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? FatherId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I did this:

1. Scaffolded a full controller for Person with index, create, edit...
2. Created EditorTemplates folder in Views->Person
3. Created Person.cshtml:

   `@model TestEditorTemplate.Models.Person
   <div>
       <h4>Child</h4>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Name)
       @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.Id)
   </div>`
4. Added `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Children)` to Create.cshtml

**Questions:**

1. How can `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Children)`possibly work with the
   editor template when `m.Children` is a collection of `Person` and not a single
   `Person`?
2. I want to create (not edit) a father including children at the same time. That means that I have no Ids to pass to the Create view to start with. How can this work? From the example by Shyju, the Ids are already created beforehand?? Or did I just misunderstand the example?

Comment: post your view please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **EditorTemplates** to handle this. Here is a working sample.

So i have a viewmodel to represent the father-child relationship

```
public class PersonVM
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int? ParentId { set; get; }
    public List<PersonVM> Childs { set; get; }
}
```

And in my GET action method, i create an object of my view model and load the Father -childs data to it.

```
public ActionResult EditorTmp(int id = 1)
{
    //Hard coded for demo, you may replace with actual DB values
    var person = new PersonVM {Id = 1, Name = "Mike"};
    person.Childs = new List<PersonVM>
    {
        new PersonVM {Id = 2, Name = "Scott", ParentId = 11},
        new PersonVM {Id = 2, Name = "Gavin", ParentId = 12}
    };
    return View(person);
}
```

Now i will create an EditorTemplate. To do that, Go to your Views folder, and Create a directory called **EditorTemplates** under the directory which has same name as the controller, and add a view with name `PersonVM.cshtml`

[image]

Now, go to this view and add the below code.

```
@model ReplaceWithYourNameSpaceNameHere.PersonVM
<div>
    <h4>Childs </h4>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.Id)
</div>
```

Now let's go back to our main view. We need to make this view strongly typed to our original `PersonVM`. We will use the EditorFor html helper method in this view to call our editor template

```
@model ReplaceWithYourNameSpaceNameHere.PersonVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.Id)
    </div>
    @Html.EditorFor(s=>s.Childs)
   <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Now have an HttpPost method in the controller to handle the form posting

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditorTmp(PersonVM model)
{
    int fatherId = model.Id;
    foreach (var person in model.Childs)
    {
        var id=person.Id;
        var name = person.Name;
    }
    // to do  : Save ,then Redirect (PRG pattern)
    return View(model);
}
```

Now, If you put a break point in your HttpPost action method, you can see the Id's of childs are passed to this action method.

[image]

One important thing to remember is, Your Editor Template view's name should be same as the type you are binding to it.

Comment: Great detailed answer, but I have some additional questions. Would you mind sharing you project? Please see revised question.

Comment: I needed to add a `HiddenFor` to the ParentId in the edit template to make this work :

         @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.ParentId)

Comment: So how do I add new entries? Is there a way to write a template for `ICollection<PersonVM>`?